# Magento 2: Is there a "safer" way to run Composer Upgrade without enable allow_url_fopen?

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, composer

I had an issue with running Composer Upgrade command due to `allow_url_fopen` is not `enabled` in `PHP.ini`. I ended up consulting the host provider and they recommended against having this parameter `enabled` for long period of time. Since my hosting environment does not give me a direct access to modify this parameter, do we have a different option?

I also notice that the web UI updater and product image importer wouldn't work either if `allow_url_fopen` is `disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your hosting should be M2 compatible, if it's not then you'll run into quite few issues as M2 isn't as lenient as M1.

You can add `php_value allow_url_fopen On` in root htaccess file as a workaround and give that a try.

If above doesn't help and your host is using suPHP, you can create `php.ini` file in root directory and add `allow_url_fopen = On` in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding that change to .htaccess on /public_html folder end up throwing an error 500 because "php_value" is invalid command on my host environment (Cpanel). Is there any written documentation stating that Magento 2 require "allow_url_fopen" to run? I'm looking at the Magento 2 requirement page, it didn't mention anything about that.

Comment: DevDocs only specify generic hosting/environment requirements and don't list all the settings required to run M2. It's generally the hosting company that ensures the compatibility and changes PHP and other settings accordingly. I've edited answer above I hope it helps.